# Does resize event with search event are Independent ? ListView + TextBox c#

Tags: c#, listview, search, resize

Working on application which is searching for items in ListView. I've added a liitle bit logic for this to looks better. 
First I have added logic to the `List View Columns` - size of column fit to the content.
Then searching via ID - which is working.
My problem and question is if these two events depends of each other ? mean.. while I am trying to search it gets to infinitive loop with resizing and it makes "crash". My code which depends of that is :

// Resize

```
  void DeviceListView_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            controller.ResizeColumns((ListView)sender);
        }

 public void ResizeColumns(ListView lv)
        {
            foreach (ColumnHeader column in lv.Columns)
            {
                column.Width = -2;
            }
        }
```

// Search

```
void SearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            controller.Search();
        }

public void Search()
        {
            myListView.Items.Clear();
            myListView.Items.AddRange(myList.Where(i => string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBox.Text) || searchBox.Text.Contains("Search") || i.esn.Contains(searchBox.Text))
            .Select(c => new ListViewItem (
                new string[] {c.ID, c.Name, (...), c.Smth}
            )).ToArray());
        }
```

// Search Box place holder

```
void SearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            controller.Search();
        }

        void TextGotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
            if(tb.Text == "Search...")
            {
                tb.Text = "";
                tb.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }

        void TextLostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
            if(tb.Text == "")
            {
                tb.Text = "Search...";
                tb.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
            }
        }
```

The whole application already have a lot of lines of code, posted just pice of this.
Btw. My suspicions are in `Search` method in the line which contains : `myListView.Items.Clear();` If i do not cleare it it wont makes anything, but Search wont have usage as well.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are independent of each other, somehow - I do not know :) If solved my problem which look like :

global variable :

```
bool resized = false;

if (!resized)
{
            foreach (ColumnHeader column in lv.Columns)
            {
                column.Width = -2;
            }
            resized = true;
 }
```